# Nodejs : serverless - Image corrupted when using lambda to upload image to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, api-gateway

I am using serverless with Nestjs
I have an endpoit to upload an image to s3
when I run the dev server the image gets uploaded normally to s3
but when I use lambda the image is uploaded to s3 but when I try to view it or download it ,the file is corrupted
I made some research and I think it's related to the api-gateway
I allowed all files in api gateway but the file stays corrupted

Can someone help me with this issue ,please

// serverless.yml

```
service: casino-service-api

useDotenv: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-*************************
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-*****************
      - subnet-*****************
  region: sa-east-1
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: production
     ............
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - 'image/*'
      - 'application/pdf'
      - 'application/msword'
      - 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'

functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/src/serverless.handler
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: '{proxy+}'

configValidationMode: error
```

// the function I use to upload to s3

```
 import { PutObjectCommandInput, S3 } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
  constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService) {
    this.s3 = new S3({
      apiVersion: process.env.AWS_API_VERSION,
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    });
  }
async uploadToS3(file: IFile, path: string): Promise<string> {
    const bucket = `${process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET}`;
    const region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
    const key = `casino/${path}/${file.originalname}`;

    const fileToBeUploaded: PutObjectCommandInput = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Body: file.buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Key: key,
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      ContentType: file.mimetype,
    };

    try {
      await this.s3.putObject(fileToBeUploaded);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading to S3:', error);
      throw error;
    }
    return `https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
  }
```

I tried uploading using the devserver and using deploying the code to EC2 and it worked
I tried uploading directly to the s3 and it also worked

I just need to understand which part is incorrect

Comment: can we see the handler too (at least the important parts)? as well - are the binaries posted directly or as an multipart upload?